# Value of x for f(x) to be continuous

Tags: limits

> If $$f(x) = \frac{\ln(1 + x^3 (\tan x)^2)}{e^{x^3}  - e^{\sin^3 x}}$$  is continuous at $x=0$ then $f(0)$  must be?

I have tried both expansion of $\ln(1 + x)$  and and L'hospital rule but I am unable to get it right

Comment: Please check that I've reformatted your question correctly.

Comment: That seems a strange way to ask for the limit of an expression at a value where the expression is not defined: define a function $f$ in terms of an expression that is not defined at zero, and then ask what happens if that function (which isn't defined at zero, according to its definition) is continuous at zero. One could instead say one has a function $f$ that is continuous at zero and defined according to this expression everywhere else. I suppose that is what was meant.

Comment: Really check that expression to make sure it's correct. The way you showed it originally was very unclear. The expression shown here appears to diverge at $x=0,$ so there would not be any value of $f(0)$ that could make it continuous.

Comment: Evaluate the limit of the function as $x\to 0$. Using standard limits the numerator can be replaced by $x^5$ and denominator can be replaced by $x^3-\sin^3x$. Now the desired limit is $2$.

Comment: @ParamanandSingh Yes sir the answer is correct. I was thinking to do this but I thought that by doing this, I am applying the limits two times in a question.Thank you.